# How can I play an animation on page load in jQuery so that it plays for index.php but not e.g. other_page.php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, animation, pageload

I want to play an animation on page load but only for my index.php and not for every other page of my website.

Is there something like this for jQuery:

```
$('index.php').ready(function());
```

?

If not how can I achieve the desired effect?

Comment: Just include the javascript code for the animation in that php file in which you want the animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put your jQuery code in index.php page only using any of the following jquery load functions.

`$(window).load(function(){...});`

or

`$(document).ready(function(){...});`

or

`$('body').onload(function(){...});`

by this your animation will run only on index.php page and not any other page.

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the url with Javascript and then fire your function to play

```
if(
window.location.href=="address to check"
)
 your_function();
{
/* some code to load */
}else{
document.write('<div>testing my super loaded div code sample</div>')
}
}
```